# NSWindow shadow disappears after running Cocoa animation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout, nswindow

Please observe the following gif. What you see is me clicking on a disclosure button that slides out a table view. So far so good. When I hide and reopen the table view, you will see the shadow of the window disappearing. This is not intentional. The shadow re-appears when I hide the table view again.

[image]

I use the following code to achieve this effect:

```
- (void) showListView {

    NSView * listView = self.listViewController.view;
    NSView * timerView = self.timerViewController.view;
    timerView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor windowBackgroundColor].CGColor;

    [self.view addSubview:listView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:nil];

    self.listViewEdgesToEdgesOfSuperviewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[listView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(listView)];
    [self.view addConstraints:self.listViewEdgesToEdgesOfSuperviewConstraints];

    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *ctx) {
        self.timerViewBottomToSuperViewConstraint.animator.constant += listView.frame.size.height;
    } completionHandler:^{

    }];


}

- (void) hideListView {

    NSView * listView = self.listViewController.view;

    // Animate the disappearance of the list view
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext * context){
        self.timerViewBottomToSuperViewConstraint.animator.constant = 0;

    } completionHandler:^{

        [self.view removeConstraints:self.listViewEdgesToEdgesOfSuperviewConstraints];
        [listView removeFromSuperview];

    }];



}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get fix this so that the shadow is showing? I haven't tried any of my own solutions that I can share, since I'm at a loss of what to do.

I'd be happy to provide any other information you need.

EDIT: Uploaded a new gif that better illustrates the problem.

Comment: Shadow on `NSWindow` ... Kinda hell sometimes ... Did you try to call `invalidateShadow` on `NSWindow` when it changes frame?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I call 'invalidateShadow' in the completionHandler? That doesn't seem to work. Or should I call it for every frame update (i.e. each frame of the animation)?

Comment: Not proud of it, but in one of my app, I have to call this every time window frame changes ... Otherwise I was scratching my head for a few weeks and shadow was still crippled. Especially when I started to play animations, layers, ... Can't explain why, but this fixed it. https://gist.github.com/robertvojta/9528018

Comment: Hmm, thanks for sharing the code. It doesn't seem to be working in my case, unfortunately. There is no visible change.

Comment: I'm still curious, can you zip the whole project (sources) and upload it somewhere? Remove everything, just reproducible case. If it's not secret? Will check directly on my Mac.

Comment: Please see https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqiq9d6yamt7jv8/Project.zip.

Comment: Will take a look during weekend.